# Continuous background update location

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

I want my app to update location continuous in background. I have implemented below code.

```
 locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically =false
 self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
 locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
 locationManager.delegate = self
 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
 locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=true
 locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
 self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

- This code manage in `appdelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` to be able to receive location updates even when your app is running in the background. `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` only gives you authorisation to receive location updates while your app is running in the foreground.

Comment: and add the Location updates in Background Modes in the capabilities list if I remember rightly

Comment: @JaiminPatel you simply need to change `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` to `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`

Comment: please try to read from Apple & Google first https://www.raywenderlich.com/966-geofencing-tutorial-with-core-location

Comment: something 15 mins after not update location in background.